# delay for loop before Iteration not working

Tags: java, for-loop, timer

All I want is to wait for a little time before next iteration **without blocking the thread** since other process must go on.

Tried Timer, but nothing works inside the for loop.

I'm stuck.

There is a method which must execute and it takes about 20 seconds to execute.

My for loop is below

```
int[] ids ={1,2,3,4,5,6,87,234,6,346,3,4634,12};

        for (int i= 0, len = ids.length; i<len;i++) {
            Log.e(" Need to wait: ", " for every widget to update~");
            final int[] timesRun = {0};
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timesRun[0] = timesRun[0] + 1;
                    Log.e("timesRun", String.valueOf(timesRun[0]));

                    Log.i("tag", "runs every 5 seconds");
                    if (timesRun[0] == 10) {
                        myProcessfor20Seconds();
                        timer.cancel();

                    }
                }
            }, 0, 5000);

            Log.i("tag", "Exiting the Timer");


        }
```

and this also

```
int[] ids ={1,2,3,4,5,6,87,234,6,346,3,4634,12};

    for (int i= 0, len = ids.length; i<len;i++) {
        Log.e(" Need to wait: ", " for every widget to update~");
       final AtomicInteger timesRun = new AtomicInteger(0);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timesRun.addAndGet(1);

                Log.e("timesRun", String.valueOf(timesRun.get()));

                Log.i("tag", "runs every 5 seconds");
                if (timesRun.intValue() ==  10) {
                    timer.cancel();

                }
            }
        }, 0, 5000);

        Log.i("tag", "Exiting the Timer");


    }
```

However the logcat is like this

```
2023-01-12 11:14:28.919 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.920 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.920 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.920 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.920 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.920 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15175/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15175/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15174/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15174/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15176/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15177/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15177/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.921 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15178/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15178/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15180/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15180/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15181/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15176/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15181/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15179/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.922 15096-15182/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15179/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15182/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15183/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15183/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15184/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15184/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15096/com.my.app E/ Need to wait::  for every widget to update~
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15185/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15185/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15096/com.my.app I/tag: Exiting the Timer
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15186/com.my.app E/timesRun: 1
2023-01-12 11:14:28.923 15096-15186/com.my.app I/tag: runs every 5 seconds
2023-01-12 11:14:28.946 15096-15096/com.my.app D/IS_CTS_MODE: false
2023-01-12 11:14:28.946 15096-15096/com.my.app D/MULTI_WINDOW_SWITCH_ENABLED: false
2023-01-12 11:14:29.026 15096-15096/com.my.app E/getting from HAWK :: 1
```

```
myProcessfor20Seconds();
```

is executed after all iteration are completed.

Seems like I need something Synchronized but I'm stuck and I'm still learning.
Please help.

Comment: Do you want a 5 second *gap* between executions for your 20-second method, or do you want to start your 20-second method every 5 seconds?

Comment: Why the condition `timesRun[0] == 10`? Also using `final int[] timesRun = {0};` is super unsafe. There is a reason why the compiler does not allow you to use a simple `int` for that and you tried to trick it with an array. Each timer will run in its own thread and modify the same variable without any protection. You can use `AtomicInteger timesRun = new AtomicInteger(0);` instead.

Comment: @Bohemian I want a 5 second gap between execution for the 20-second method..
and the 20 second method should execute on the next iteration.

Comment: @Pavel I have updated the code with AtomicIntegar as well. But the results are no different. Logcat is same.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple: Start a thread to run your method with a gap between executions and wait in the main thread for it to finish.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    for (int i = 0, len = ids.length; i < len; i++) {
        myProcessfor20Seconds();
        try {
            if (i < len - 1) // don't sleep after the last execution
                Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}); // create the Thread with your background code as a Runnable

t.start(); // start the background thread

// Do other stuff while the Thread is running

try {
    t.join(); // wait for thread to finish
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

There are more elegant ways to handle the exceptions, but this is the basics.

Comment: This isn't working.. 
I have used Thread.sleep in several ways but it blocks my code. and somehow the whole app is stuck.
As I asked before **without blocking the thread** .. 
please is there any way to overcome this without Thread.sleep

Comment: @User521 this does *not* block anything in the "Do other stuff while the Thread is running" section - it can't. It's running in the background. Unless your `myProcessfor20Seconds()` does something that blocks what you claim is being blocked or your hardware has only one thread available.